# New message background highlighting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have created a comment system using ajax and php with the usage of append system now I am looking to make it look more attractive so I want when ever a new comment is posted it should be highlighted background like background color fadein and then fadeout smoothly like whenever new answer is posted it is highlighted with an orange background color can anyone help me out how it would be done and what jquery function is used

my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#sub_comment').on('click', function() {
    var comment  = $('#comment').val();
    var store_id = $('#store_id').val();

    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        $('#wait').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
        $('#wait').css('display', 'none');
    });

    $.ajax({
        type     :  "POST",
        data     :  {comment: comment, store_id: store_id, command: 'Comment'},
        dataType :  'text',
        url      :  "includes/get_data.php",
        success  :  function(data) {
                        $('#comment').val('');
                        $('#comments').append($(data).hide().fadeIn(2000));
                    }
    });

});
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle?

Comment: can you provide a codepen?

Comment: not familiar with codepen I am trying to create a fiddle hope this will work

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ercq4jx8/ here is the fiddle

Comment: @AbhayNaik I added external ajax file but don't knwo it is properly added or not as i am new to fiddle

Comment: @MarkAlan I have added a answer. You can check if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `transition: background-color 1s linear;` css property.
Set initial background to the comment div and add the above property. Then change the background (to orange) of the div, it will create a fadein effect and after some setTimeout remove this background, then it will create a fadeout effect.
Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/axabX/) example for reference.

Another way is to use the animation property of CSS. An example is given [here](https://jsfiddle.net/AjayPalSingh/qcoqw5rp/3/)

Comment: normal color will be trasparent and transition I have to set via jquery ??

Comment: no the css property will automatically create a linear transition with speed of 1s (check the above example)

Comment: Please check the color stays red

Comment: I found another approach to do this. Check https://jsfiddle.net/AjayPalSingh/qcoqw5rp/3/ this..

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
$('#comments').append($(data).hide().fadeIn(2000));
```

cannot work because data is text. You have to make something like

```
$('#comments').append(data).hide().fadeIn(2000);
```

but this will always hide all comments and show them again. A workaround is to put the new comment to a new container and only handle this one:

```
var comments = $('#comments').append('<div>' + data + '</div>');
$('div',comments).css('background-color','');
var newcom = $('div:last-child',comments);
newcom.hide().css('background-color','#ffff00').fadeIn(2000);
```

With the newcom object you can do any css transition or other things.

Comment: When I did this it hid lighted all comments and the background did not went to normal it stayed what you set did not faded out

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

> Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sub_comment').on('click', function() {
    var apend_data = '<div class="data orange"><p>Hello World</p></div>';
    $('#comments').append($(apend_data).hide().fadeIn(2000));
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#comments .data").removeClass('orange');
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

> Css

```
#comments {
  width: 100%;
}

.data {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

> HTML

```
<div id="comments">
  <div class="data">
    <p>
      Hello World
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="sub_comment">
  Click Me
</button>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abhaysnaik22/ercq4jx8/7/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $(() => {
            var index = 1;
            $('#btnSubmit').on('click', () => {
                 
                $("#conteiner").append('<p id="_' + index + '" style="display:none;width:50%" class="backColor"> ' + $('#txtComment').val() + ' </p>');
                var id = "#_" + index + "";
                $(id).fadeIn();
                index++;

                setInterval(function () {
                    $(id).removeClass('backColor');
                }, 1000);
            });

        });
```

```css
 .backColor {
         background-color:red;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class='row' id='conteiner' style="padding-left:50px">

    </div>
    <br />
    <div class='row' style='width:50%;padding-left:50px'>
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtComment" placeholder="comment">
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id='btnSubmit'>Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  
      
    
</body>

</html>
```